# How to select a cell in the Tktable without editing state?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I'm using the Tktable package to draw the table, below example:

```
package require Tktable
global TableValue
array set TableValue {
    0,1 Col1 0,2 Col2 1,0 Row1 2,0 Row2 1,1 a 1,2 b 2,1 c 2,2 d 
}
table .t -rows 3 -cols 3 -titlerows 1 -titlecols 1 -variable TableValue
pack .t
```

When i click the cell, how to just show the cell selected state not editing state that I can use "Delete" to clear the cell content and if I double click the cell then show editing state. How to realize that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Probably the greatest visual control you can achieve with a table widget is done by embedding widgets in the table. This is because the table has default bindings that are difficult to override to your specifications. But you **can** insert widgets as illustrated below, and completely control their appearance. Play around with attributes and bindings as you like. But this should be a fair start.

```
package require Tktable

array set TableTitles {
    0,1 Col1 0,2 Col2 1,0 Row1 2,0 Row2, 1,1 a 1,2 b 2,1 c 2,2 d
}


table .t -rows 3 -cols 3 -titlerows 1 -titlecols 1 -variable TableTitles
pack .t

proc EnableEntry { entry } {
    $entry configure -state normal -cursor ibeam
    $entry selection range 0 end
}

foreach row [list 1 2] {
    foreach col [list 1 2] {
        set cell [set row],[set col]
        # Use the array already created for the entry variable
        set entry [entry .t.e$row$col -justify center -textvariable TableTitles($cell) \
            -highlightthickness 1 -highlightcolor blue -state disabled \
            -disabledbackground white -disabledforeground black -cursor arrow]

        bind $entry <Double-Button-1> "EnableEntry $entry"
        bind $entry <Button-1> "focus $entry"
        bind $entry <FocusOut> "$entry configure -state disabled -cursor arrow"
        .t window configure $cell -window $entry
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your exhaustive explanation.